# WebAPI 2 Get action, parameter is always null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am certain this is simple.
I have a controller with one method in it:

```
<RoutePrefix("Api/Stock")>
Public Class StockController
    Inherits ApiController

    <Route("{id}")>
    Public Function [Get](id As String, cred As credentials) As IHttpActionResult
        Try
            Using conn As New serviceInterface(serviceInterface.serverType.test)
                Dim stockItem = New stockItem() With {
                    .lotNo = id
                }

                Dim result = conn.webServicesAdvanced.stockHubAction(cred, stockItem)

                Return Ok(result.obj)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return InternalServerError(ex)
        End Try

        Return BadRequest()
    End Function
End Class
```

As you can see, I allow 2 parameters:

- The id (or lotnumber)
- And the credentials object

My credentials object is stored as a string in a cookie. Now, I have tried many things to get a $.get call to work, but I keep getting the **cred** object as null.
Here is one example of my call:

```
self.lotEnquiry = function () {
    var lot = self.lotNumber();

    if (lot.length == 10) { // Our lot numbers are 10 characters long
        var cred = { cred: $.parseJSON(dataModel.getUserObject()) };

        console.log(cred);

        $.get(stockUrl + "/" + lot, cred)
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //app.navigateToLotEnquiry();
            })
            .fail(app.handleError);
    }
};
```

and this still shows as null.
I have tried building an object with the id and credentials specified:

```
var cred = {
    id: self.lotNumber,
    cred: $.parseJSON(dataModel.getUserObject())
};
```

or even as just the object itself:

```
var cred = $.parseJSON(dataModel.getUserObject());
```

and I have even tried just submitting it as a string.

No matter what I try, the object is always null (but if I do a console.log I can see everything).

Can someone point out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I was trying to supply a JSON object to **HttpGet**. This was appending to the URL. To be able to send data as JSON I have to use **HttpPost or HttpPut**.